# Iphone Sqlite problem

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have to make a project using sqlite, i would rather use simple plists, xml or even core data as i don't have any experience with sql. However it has to be able to read from sqlite database. I downloaded the FMDB wrapper and set it up quickly however when i try and read from my database it does not display in the tableview, Here is my code:

```
TermsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sql"];
FMDatabase *db  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];
[db open];

FMResultSet *fResult= [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM country WHERE id=1"];

while([fResult next])
{

    CountryString = [fResult stringForColumn:@"name"];

    [CountryArray addObject:CountryString];

    NSLog(@"The data is %@=",CountryString);
}
[db close];
  }
```

and i display it in my tableview using this:

```
NSString *Text = [CountryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = Text;
```

Now i don't get any errors, however the array is always empty, in the console i don't get any warnings etc either but i noticed that the NSLOG never shows up, so i don't think that part is working.
Heres my sql file in a text editor:

```
 CREATE TABLE country ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250),location TEXT,number INTERGER);
  INSERT INTO country (name,location,number) VALUES('UK','country location here',1);
```

Also how are sqlite files supposed to be like? I created one using a sqlite editor and it produced a sql file, when i open it in a text editor i just see sql statements?

It would be really great it someone could help me with this,

Thanks!

Comment: Is the file extension correct ? Most of the time, the file extension for SQLite DBs is `.sqlite`, not `.sql`.

Comment: @DarkDust the extension for SQLite database files doesn't matter.

Comment: Hey thanks, but i've tried both and their was no change.

Comment: @WTP: It does matter insofar as the `pathForResource:ofType:` must match his filename in the bundle. If the file does not exist and SQLite isn't told *explicitly* to open the file read-only, then SQLite simply creates an empty DB which would totally explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks but it is definitely the right filename.

Comment: I have edited my question with my sql file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it, It was a problem with my sql file, it now works great! Thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 0):

just copy the  sql statements and run it in the sql console
after that u have to backup the database
using .backup

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, i think this may be the problem as the .sql file is just a list of commands. How would i go about doing this? Thanks!